# Confused about helpers that shouldn't be included but are...I think

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, helper

I have a bunch of pages re-using the same elements, so I created four helpers that throw those elements in automatically.

In `application.html.erb` all of these helpers are rendered but I'm confused as to how to make a new page that isn't affected by the helpers.

I tried creating a new view and controller and building the page in that view's subdirectory but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`application.html.erb` is the base template for all of your views, so anything you put in there is going to be rendered in all of your views. If you want to display different content on a view, you'll need to set the layout explicitly in the controller.

```
def some_method
  layout :some_other_layout_template
end
```

For more info, checkout the [Rails Guides on Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: Sure thing! Hope my answer helped, and if it did, please mark it as correct :)